# How to programmatically calibrate Autodesk forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

The measurement tool of the viewer has calibration tool. It requires that user selects two points in the viewer and define the distance with proper units.

My plan is that I will have the points defined in my model at a fixed distance. I will not need user input for this. How do I add the distance, unit, and size so as to programmatically set the calibration?

**Edit: The workaround.**

I need that the default units be meters and it should correctly show 1 meter on the model to 1 meter as measured by measurement tool.

For the time being, what I did is -

I **manually calibrate** the model using calibrate tool to meters by picking two known points in the model.

Then I used this to get the scale factor -

```
var measureExtension =NOP_VIEWER.getExtension('Autodesk.Measure')
var factor = measureExtension.getCalibrationFactor()
```

(I used the above code lines in the developer console of the browser while interacting with the viewer simultaneously.)

which gave me this value factor = 0.039369.
I am **adding this scale factor in my code** once the model is loaded again.

```
measureExtension.calibrateByScale('m', 0.039369)
```

This seems to **solve the issue for the models that I have with me**. 
I know this will break once I have some different model with different default units. Please let me know if someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a quick guess by looking at the viewer3D.js source:

```
var measureExt = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Measure')

// pick from available values:
// 'decimal-ft'
// 'ft-and-fractional-in'
// 'ft-and-decimal-in'
// 'decimal-in'
// 'fractional-in'
// 'm'
// 'cm'
// 'mm'
// 'm-and-cm'

measureExt.calibrate('decimal-in', 10)
```

Comment: Thank you Philippe.
I had tried this, it requires that measurement has already picked two points so as to map that distance with the size that we are providing. I don't think it works independently.

Please check my edit section in the answer for the workaround I am using.